# Qual è il significato di "venir messo nel conto dello zelo" in questo brano?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *La chimera*, di Sebastiano Vassalli, ho letto:

> Servizievoli fino alla nausea con i frati, assidui in chiesa e alle funzioni religiose, attenti a tutto ciò che gli succedeva attorno e che succedeva attorno a piazza San Quirico, i due furfanti divenuti frati laici erano riusciti a mettere radici all’ombra augusta e terribile del Tribunale dell’Inquisizione di Novara come certi fungacci incommestibili riescono a crescere nei luoghi più strani, per esempio nelle cantine o nei ripostigli delle case; e non solo vi avevano messo radici, ma vi prosperavano con ogni genere di traffici e d’intrighi, all’esterno e anche all’interno del convento: dove la loro intraprendenza non disturbava nessuno, anzi, per ciò che se ne sapeva, **veniva messa nel conto dello zelo**. «È così premuroso, così attento!» soleva dire Manini di Taddeo: spalancando i grandi occhi grigiazzurri, e muovendo le mani. «Così zelante e sollecito ad ogni nostro desiderio, ed anche così pio!» (Effettivamente, ogni volta che i suoi traffici lo spingevano ad allontanarsi per qualche giorno dal convento dei Domenicani e dall’annesso Tribunale, Taddeo giustificava le sue assenze con pratiche devote: voti resi, pellegrinaggi o visite a santuari, elemosine ed altre opere di pietà.)

Non capisco cosa voglia dire l'espressione "veniva messa nel conto dello zelo" in questo brano. Ho cercato alla voce "conto" su parecchi dizionari, ma non sono riuscita a trovare niente che abbia senso in questo contesto. Potreste spiegarmi il significato di questa locuzione nel passaggio precedente?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Mettere in conto" è un'espressione figurata che significa "considerare", "valutare" o "classificare" 
(immagina un commerciante: quando mette in conto qualcosa significa che gli sta assegnando un valore).

Vedi anche la definizione che viene data qui:  http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/C/conto.shtml

> mettere in c., [...] ~fig. preventivare, calcolare come possibile

In questo caso significa che l'intraprendenza e il darsi da fare dei due individui non destava sospetti perché 
era considerata  come una manifestazione di zelo da parte dei due e questa spiegazione era considerata plausibile.